# 'for' loop replaceable with 'foreach'

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach, compiler-warnings

My code is:

```
ArrayList<People> people = new ArrayList<>();

// people.add(...);
// people.add(...);

        for (int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++) {
            if (people.get(i) > 60.0)
                System.out.println(people.get(i).toString());
        }
```

And I get the following warning:

> 'for' loop replaceable with 'foreach'

How should I modify the loop using foreach?

Thanks.

Comment: `for (People person : people) { ....}`, but surely you've looked this up, no?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Comment: `(people.get(i) > 60.0)` - does this code compile? how can you compare a People instance with a double constant?

Comment: Is this really a compiler warning?  I didn't think the compiler cared.  My IDE gives me this warning.

Comment: @Eran, each of the List-people's element contains a double value.

Comment: @tieTYT, I'm using Intellij IDEA 13, compiler gives a really useful tips ;)

Comment: @MarkKorzhov If each people element is a double why do you need the class "People"? Doesn't make any sense to me. I can't imagine why one would declare own types to hide the standard types...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A list called `people` would normally contain `Person` objects.

Here's some example code that shows how to use a for-each loop:

```
public class Demo {

    private static class Person {
       public int age;
       public String name;

       public Person(int age, String name) {
           this.age = age;
           this.name = name;
       }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {

        // Create and populate a list of people with individuals
        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
        people.add(new Person(32, "Fred"));
        people.add(new Person(45, "Ginger"));
        people.add(new Person(66, "Elsa"));

        // Iterate over the list (one person at a time)
        for (Person person : people) {
            if (person.age > 60) {
                System.out.println("Old person: " + person.name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also read the [Oracle Java documentation about for-each loops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).

The general form is:

```
for (Person person : people) {
    ...
}
```

Instead of:

```
for (int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++) { 
    Person person = people.get(i);
    ...
}
```

The for-each is usually recommended because it's terser.
However, if you need to know the index number of the item you will have to use
the original for loop or increment a counter inside the for-each.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(People objPeople : people){
//Loop's code
}
```

Official documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
people.get(i) retrun an object of class People.
```

You can not compare a object with a number in if statement.

**EDIT**

How to iterate Arraylist

```
1)

for (int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++) {
   if(people.get(i).getAvalue() > 60.0 ){//your code}
}
```

2)

```
for(People p: people){
  if(p.getAvalue()>60.0){//you code}
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: This is the mistake in code. all other answer was about parse the arraylist.

Comment: It's not relevant to the question though.

Comment: If I make a so serious mistake, I can delete my answer, and end the misunderstanding

Answer (score 1):

You can replace that loop with for each as follow:

```
ArrayList<People> peopleList = new ArrayList<>();

for(People people:peopleList)
{
Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the for loop easier to comprehend later on.  Add this comment prior to code to disable inspection for this case only.

```
//noinspection ForLoopReplaceableByForEach
for (int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++) { 
    Person person = people.get(i);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is replaceable but I don't understand what problem Lint sees with "old school for loop". It works in both ways.

Seems to be religious stuff:

"So when should you use the for-each loop? Any time you can. It really beautifies your code." (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in other answers, the comparison needs to be against some property of a Person (age?).

Assuming you make the comparison fix, a stream version of the for loop might look like the following:

```
people.stream()
    .filter(p -> p.getAge() > 60.0)
    .forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.toString());
```